# Pattern/approach for frontend-backend data integration and fetching

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, frontend, backend

I have been applying a pattern in some small apps I worked on, which next tools:

Frontend: ReactJS, Redux, Firebase (only authentication stuff)
Backend: Node with Express and the library for the database I was using (mysql or mongo)

The flow used to be like this:

1. Page loading and validating if user is signed in. If yes, fetching app data with backend. If not, just checking if user is not on a protected route and then let him navigate (create account, reset password, etc)
2. When fetch occurs and user signed in, backend send all data from that user (categories, stores, products, profile and any other info to let application run fluid) so when navigating there is not continuously loading to fetch each chunk of data. This also happens like this because is not a big amount of data (at the beginning), lets say maybe 1 or 2 stores with 15-20 products each one.
3. When updating data like changing product name, price or any kind of data mutation, the frontend send a request to the backend and then the update is done and a response of success true/false is sent as an answer for the request.
4. Let's say the previous step is a store creation. So, the frontend receives the success response and then dispatch an APPEND_STORE event to redux store to catch the new store with its data (only the ID + other data which is created on the backend is received as response on http request, data which was generated at the frontend is taken from the app itself) and append it to the stores array and then set the store array object again.
5. The reason why the previous step occurs like that is to avoid the backend first make the update and then make a new query to get again the new register (ej: create new store request -> backend creates the store and retrieve the new ID -> backend find/query the new register with its ID -> answer the data)

So, basically the question is about the pattern. So far this pattern had not give big troubles by now but I'm pretty sure there are some details I haven't seen from this point and also I think there are recommended ways to handle this that I couldn't find on internet yet.

I would like to know the best approach for this (or at least a better approach from the above) in order to implement it to bigger applications to handle more users and data which will increase as time goes.

Main questions:

1. When loading, should the backend process all data and send it to the frontend or should send minimal data to let the application begin and then send as navigation requires? I was also thinking when data grows up send a chunk of data with limit of 10/20 registers to keep the same approach but want to know the standard/correct way to handle it.
2. When a data validation fails on backend, should the backend answer with an OK status code with a key called success: "true/false" and additional data to handle this on the frontend, or should the backend answer with an error status code?
3. As I said, backend only answer with the data created by backend itself (ID, creation date, etc). Should the backend answer only with this or should backend make a new query to get full register and send it as response? Initially took this approach in order to optimize resources (minimum quantity of request and data sent by response). I'm also thinking maybe this is a dumb approach because today's world have a lot of resources so that difference should not change performance of anything. Also, with this answer my behavior on redux will change. Do you have any comments also from this redux approach?
4. Is it ok to make a query to database to first update and then another query to fetch all registered again? I know databases are created to handle multiple queries but I don't know if there are some cons to take on mind when doing like this.

Really thanks!